How do I make an element with a set aspect ratio fill as much available space as possible without overflowing?
I have a div. I want to enforce its aspect ratio. As long as its set aspect ratio is preserved and my div is neither wider nor higher than the available vertical / horizontal space, I want it to occupy this space to the greatest extend possible.
In other words, assume I want to enforce the aspect ratio of 4:3. Then:

if the enclosing container is 120px : 120px, then I want my div to have width of 120px, height of 90px and to be vertically centered;
if the enclosing container is 240px : 120px, then I want my div to instead have width of 160px, height of 120px and to be horizontally centered.

How do I do so?
I tried:


body {
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
}

.inner {
    background-color: white;
    aspect-ratio: calc(2 * sqrt(3)) / 3;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"/>
</div>



This appears to work, but only as long as the browser window is not made narrow. If you make the browser window narrow, then .inner's width will overflow available horizontal space, which is unacceptable for me.
It appears this is enforced by height: 100%;. Trying to preserve both aspect-ratio and height the browser will set width to unacceptably large values. However, height: 100%; appears necessary, otherwise .inner will have dimensions of 0x0! If I try to correct this behavior by setting max-width: 100% and the browser window is narrow, then the browser will ignore aspect-ratio and instead just set both width and height to the width/height of the enclosing container, which is again unacceptable for me.
Is there any way to do what I need to do?

from the duplicate, replace this line width:min(90%, min(960px, 90vh*(var(--r)))); with width:min(100%,100vh*(var(--r)));

@TemaniAfif Thank you. But what if the height of the enclosing container is not necessarily equal to 100vh?

replace it with the actual height you know

@TemaniAfif :( this is the only way? this is inconvenient if the element is deeply nested

You need to know at least the width or the height. Btw, better share a more realistic code that reflect your real use case. maybe there are solutions for your specific case
